# Index numpy arrays columns by another numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to index a 2d matrix in numpy so that I can get all rows but only particular columns given by another numpy array. It's something as following:

```
a = [0,1,1,2,0,2,1]

d = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I want to get all rows from d such that column is given by a. So for above example I want,

```
t = [1,2,2,3,1,3,2]
```

I tried some of the methods given on numpy documentation but am not able to get it.

I think this is doable in matlab without any iteration. Can I do this is python without looping over something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1])
>>> d = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> d[numpy.arange(d.shape[0]), a]
array([1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2])
```

For arrays `a`, `b`, and `c` where `b` and `c` have integer dtype and `b.shape == c.shape`, advanced indexing `d = a[b, c]` gives `d[i] == a[b[i], c[i]]`.